# How can I make mathematica to recognize the variable name which contains 'i' in do loop?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica do loop, how can I make mathematica to recognize the variable name which contains 'i'?

For example, I define m1=1;m2=2;m3=3; then execute Do[H[i] = mi, {i, 1, 3}]. One of output is just H[1] = mi, instead of 1. It seems that in do loop, when deal with string and variable, mathematica would not replace the i with its corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `Symbol` :

```
Do[H[i] = Symbol["m" <> ToString[i]], {i, 3}]
```

This really is poor coding practice however. You should just make `m` a list to begin with..

```
m={1,2,3}
Do[H[i] = m[[i]], {i, 3}]
```

Comment: or `Array[(H[#] = m[[#]])&, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of `ToExpression` and `ToString`:

```
Do[H[i] = ToExpression["m" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Explanation:

- `"m" <> ToString[i]` generates the "m1", "m2"... strings ( `<>` is for strings concatenation).
- `ToExpression[]` converts these strings into Mathematica expressions

Comment: Thank u a lot, your answer solves my problem perfectly!